# Api root on django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am newbie on DRF so I wonder if there a "elegant" way to add more endpoints to API Root. I have an endpoint to manage my users and another to manage their posts, but on http://localhost:8000/api/ only profiles appears. I search for some solutions that implies change the URL but I don't want that. For example my current endpoint to get all posts is localhost:8000/api/posts that looks fine. I don't want something like api/posts/posts or similar. Is there any alternative?

```
    {
    "profiles": "http://localhost:8000/api/profiles/"
}
```

main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('docs/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger',
                                         cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('profiles.urls')),
    path('api/', include('posts.urls')),
    path('api/', include('comments.urls')),
    path('api/', include('private_messages.urls')),
]
```

userprofile urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework_simplejwt import views as jwt_views
from .views import UserProfileViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('profiles', UserProfileViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('auth/login', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
    path('auth/refresh', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view()),
]
```

posts urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import PostViewSet, PostByAuthorViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('posts', PostViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('posts-by-author/<author_id>', PostByAuthorViewSet.as_view()),
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

Answer (score 1):

> but on http://localhost:8000/api/ only profiles appears

This is the expected behavior. Django is returning the first matching path from your URL configuration file, which is the profiles module in your case. Your duplicate `api/` paths are ignored.

If you really want everything to be in `/api`, you'd have to define all your URLs in the base `urls.py` file. However, I would highly recommend you keep your current structure and add the module name to your endpoints:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('docs/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger',
                                         cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/profiles/', include('profiles.urls')),
    path('api/posts/', include('posts.urls')),
    path('api/comments/', include('comments.urls')),
    path('api/private_messages/', include('private_messages.urls')),
]
```

Otherwise your `urls.py` file can get messy very quickly as your project grows.

If a route like `localhost:8000/api/posts/posts` is bothering you, you should modify the URL configuration in your `posts` app. Something like this would probably work better for you:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostViewSet, PostByAuthorViewSet

urlpatterns = [
    path('by-author/<author_id>', PostByAuthorViewSet.as_view()),
    path('', PostViewSet.as_view())
]
```

This way you'd have the routes `localhost:8000/api/posts/`and `localhost:8000/api/posts/by-author/1`. As a side note, you should probably look into [filters](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/), since `posts-by-authors` sounds like a viewset that can easily be included in your `PostViewSet` with a query parameter.

Comment: I tried, but does not works, give me a 404 error or other kind of error. Respect to your suggestion to change post-by-author, if I use filters, the posts GET don't retrieve me all posts.